# Numbering of equations produces overfull hbox when combining gather and align

Tags: math-mode, align

I have the following code to explain the variables in the formula i use.

```
\documentclass[11pt,pointlessnumbers,a4paper,oneside,fleqn,headsepline,
parskip=half]{scrartcl} 
%
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amstext,amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\indb}[2]{{#1}_{\text{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{flalign*}
\indb{T}{N} &= b\cdot\int\nolimits_z E\cdot\indb{\alpha}{T}\cdot \theta(z) \, \diff z & \indb{\varepsilon}{N}&= \frac{\indb{T}{N}}{EA}&\\
\indb{T}{My} &= b\cdot\int\nolimits_z \indb{z}{s}\cdot E\cdot\indb{\alpha}{T}\cdot \theta(z)\, \diff z & \indb{\kappa}{y}&= \frac{\indb{T}{My}}{E\indb{I}{y}}
\end{flalign*}\\
\text{\scriptsize Anm.: obige Ausführungen gelten für einen sym. Querschnitt mit sym. Belastung um die $y$-Achse } \\
\quad\begin{matrix*}[l]
   \text{mit:} &\hspace{1.5cm}&&\\
   & \indb{T}{N}& \text{\dots} & \text{äquivalente thermische Normalkraft} \\
\end{matrix*}\notag
\end{gather*}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

When I now change the `flalign*` to `flalign` to number the two equations, the numbering is misaligned and I get an `Overfull \hbox` warning.
I really do not know what causes this. Has anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative tou your approach is use `alignat` environment (I my confess, that since now I newer see your combination of math environments:  no-numbered outside, numbered inside, this against their logic, to my opinion) :

```
\documentclass[11pt,pointlessnumbers,a4paper,oneside,
               fleqn,headsepline,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amstext,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\indb}[2]{{#1}_{\text{#2}}}

    \begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
\indb{T}{N}  & = b\cdot\int\nolimits_z E\cdot\indb{\alpha}{T}\cdot\theta(z)\diff z 
&
     \indb{\varepsilon}{N}&= \frac{\indb{T}{N}}{EA}   \\
%
\indb{T}{My} & = b\cdot\int\nolimits_z \indb{z}{s}\cdot E\cdot\indb{\alpha}{T}\cdot \theta(z)\,\diff z 
        &
\indb{\kappa}{y} & = \frac{\indb{T}{My}}{E\indb{I}{y}}
%
\intertext{\scriptsize Anm.: 
    obige Ausführungen gelten für einen sym. Querschnitt mit sym. 
    Belastung um die $y$-Achse}
\text{mit:}     &   \qquad\indb{T}{N} 
                    \quad\dots\quad
\text{äquivalente thermische Normalkraft}
                &&  \notag
\end{alignat}
\blindtext
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

**Edit:** It seems that intention of `matrix` in question's MWE is design a legend for describing symbols in equations (1) and (2). This is -- according to my opinion -- better to do outside `align` environment. Considering this, the possible solution can be:

```
\documentclass[11pt,pointlessnumbers,a4paper,oneside,
               fleqn,headsepline,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amstext,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{array}% new, for table with legend

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\indb}[2]{{#1}_{\text{#2}}}

    \begin{document}
\begin{align}%{3}
\indb{T}{N}  & = b\cdot\int\nolimits_z E\cdot\indb{\alpha}{T}\cdot\theta(z)\diff z
&
     \indb{\varepsilon}{N}&= \frac{\indb{T}{N}}{EA}   \\
%
\indb{T}{My} & = b\cdot\int\nolimits_z \indb{z}{s}\cdot E\cdot\indb{\alpha}{T}\cdot \theta(z)\,\diff z
        &
\indb{\kappa}{y} & = \frac{\indb{T}{My}}{E\indb{I}{y}}
\end{align}
%
{\scriptsize Anm.:
    obige Ausführungen gelten für einen sym. Querschnitt mit sym.
    Belastung um die $y$-Achse}
% added tabular for forms the legend
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{l >{$\displaystyle}c<{$} p{0.7\textwidth}}
 mit:   &\indb{T}{N}    & äquivalente thermische Normalkraft    \\
        &\indb{T}{My}   & \dots
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\blindtext
    \end{document}
```

In above MWE I also move comment outside from align environment. Also I replace `alignat` with `align`. Obtained result is:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but this is not really what i want to achieve. i nest the align inside the gather environment just so that i can add the matrix environment below the equations and not align the matrix itself. i use the matrix because i think it is very readable for the comments. but when i do not nest the matrix in the gather the vertical space between the align environment and the matrix is too big. your code works but doesnt prevent the aligning of the comments :/

Comment: @fuffie, I don't see any advantages to use `matrix` for writing a legend (is this its function?). You can add more lines on the same way as is showed for $T_N$ in my answer. Even better, move legend outside math environment and write it with list (as itemize) or as table. See  upgrade of my answer.

Comment: thanks, that looks pretty good, i will do it that way in the future !  nonetheless it would interesting what is causing the problem with the align envorinment nested in the gather.... but for me your solution works just as fine!

Comment: @fuffie, I'm glad to hear, that my answer help you and that you will use in future. Can you .show your contentedness with upvoting answer (by click on upper pen) at beginning of answer and even accept them (by tick on) :-).

Comment: @fuffie, regarding your problem, I thing that reading documentation for `mathtools` can explain (at least indirect), how to nest math environments. Your desired use seems not to be considered in their design.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to obtain is not very clear, but `flalign` shouldn't be nested. I propose this code, which has no `overfull \hbox`. Is it close to want you want to achieve?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,fleqn,headsepline,
parskip=half]{scrartcl}%pointlessnumbers,
%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amstext,amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\indb}[2]{{#1}_{\text{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \indb{T}{N} & = b\cdot\int\nolimits_z E\cdot\indb{\alpha}{T}\cdot \theta(z) \, \diff z & & & \indb{\varepsilon}{N} & = \frac{\indb{T}{N}}{EA} \\
  \indb{T}{My} & = b\cdot\int\nolimits_z \indb{z}{s}\cdot E\cdot\indb{\alpha}{T}\cdot \theta(z)\, \diff z & & & \indb{\kappa}{y} & = \frac{\indb{T}{My}}{E\indb{I}{y}} \\
  \shortintertext{\scriptsize Anm.: obige Ausführungen gelten für einen sym. Querschnitt mit sym. Belastung um die $y$-Achse }%
  & \mathrlap{\begin{matrix*}[l]
  \text{mit:} &\hspace{1.5cm}&&\\
  & \indb{T}{N}& \text{\dots} & \text{äquivalente thermische Normalkraft} \\
  \end{matrix*}}
\end{align*}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this would work but i am looking for a way to do that without the need of aligning the comment section with the equations. when i split the environments (without the gather) the vertical space between the matrix and the align is far too big in my opinion and i do not want to manually do the vertical aligning - but thanks for your effort